# Confidence Intervals - What's going on?

Tags: confidence-interval, dataset

I'm looking for help with this figure.

Plotted are percentages and confidence intervals for each year (I didn't collect the data).

I am wondering, under what circumstances would the confidence intervals be the same as the percentage for that year...  What's going on in the data that allows this to happen?  I thought that Confidence Intervals would appear either side of the mean, but in this case, they are not (highlighted in the graph below).

[image: Graph with Confidence Intervals]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Highly left (resp. right) skewed distribution can have the mean and lower (resp. higher) percentiles.

Comment: For reasonable confidence interval procedures, the CIs around percentages in the midrange (roughly 30 - 70%) ought to be nearly symmetric around the corresponding estimates.  Evidently, then, there *is* an inconsistency in this graphic: it is not plausible that the darker curve passes through the estimated percentages, because it generally should pass near the midpoints of each CI.

Comment: It looks indeed fishy...

Comment: @Michael M what's fishy? Do you have some technical reason to say that?

Comment: Could you add two separate histograms, one histogram showing the data distribution 2013-2014, and the second histogram showing the data distribution 2014-2015 ? That should give more depth to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Ping We don't need simulation for this!  Look at literally *any* confidence interval procedure for proportions.  Now it may be that these "percentages" aren't proportions, but even so, something really extreme and unusual must be going on for an estimate to lie at the endpoint of its CI.

Comment: @ping I invite you to consult any reference you like.  Searching our site for "binomial confidence interval" will turn up plenty of material.

Comment: I am astonished at your belligerence, @ping: what's eating you?  Maybe it's time to sit back a little and cool off.  I apologize if anything I have written might have been the cause of your feelings.

Comment: @whuber I apologize if I used a wrong tone. I would like to ask, if possible, to be a bit more detailed when someone asks for additional information. You surely have an infinitely more immense knowledge than mine. I just don't like to be treated with sufficiency. Michael M: I would also invite you to use a kinder manners when you comment. I can have put a wrong answer, and I apologize for that. You never made mistakes? If it's not ok being wrong here, I can leave the community. That's more than ok.

Comment: Good morning all, thank you all so much for your input.  It's confirmed my suspicions that the data is wildly skewed (I don't have the raw data, but I brought it up and this was explored).  I'm sorry for the delay in replaying, I've had some pretty big personal issues. Thank you all so very much for your time to comment and help out though. x